# How to solve 405 error with Python requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to login to a website with a Python script using the requests library, but I keep getting a 405 error and I'm lost on why I'm getting it.

```
import requests

payload = {
'guid': 'xxxxx',
'password': "xxxx"
}

head = {'Host': 'www.blockchain.com',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
    }

#This URL will be the URL that your login form points to with the "action" tag.
url_address = 'https://login.blockchain.com/#/login'

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(url_address, data=payload, headers = head, allow_redirects=True)

print(f'{post}')
```

I checked the form and the names of the inputfield seem to be correct as well.

What am I doing wrong in my code?

[image: passname here]
[image: loginname here]

Comment: Please [don't post screen shots of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

This was [already answered](https://serverfault.com/a/992642) on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) by [@Samit](https://serverfault.com/users/457023/samit):

> 405 status code response means the HTTP method you are trying is not
> allowed. Say, if a `PUT` request is not allowed on a server, it will
> reject the client's `PUT` request with an response code `405 Method not allowed`.
>
> So, in your case also, the `POST` method might not be allowed on which
> you are sending the request and the request is simply denying you to
> make any `POST` request by sending `405` error response.

Comment: i thought that it could also be because the request was invalid, not only serverside not allowing it.